# How to show there are no simple groups of order 760 using Sylow's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that there does not exist a simple group of order 760.
I was trying to solve it by using Sylow's Theorem but I am unable to prove it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well, what did you conclude from Sylow's theorems?

Comment: @Tobias For k=0 conclusion is fine,but what about for k=1 where 19k+1|40.

Comment: What do you mean by $k$?

Comment: n_19 congruent to 1(mod p) by Sylow's Theorem

Comment: Ok, so you can assume that the group has $20$ $19$-Sylow subgroups. How many $5$-Sylow and $2$-Sylow subgroups can it have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit more subtle than a straightforward application of Sylow's theorem.  Here is a brief sketch (omitting the details) of one possible proof.

Suppose $G$ is simple.  If $P$ is a Sylow $19$-subgroup, then $[G:N_G(P)]=20$ so that $G\hookrightarrow S_{20}$.  In fact we may assume $G\hookrightarrow A_{20}$, else $G\cap A_{20}$ is a nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$.

Let $x\in N_G(P)\setminus C_G(P)$.  Then theorem $(R)$ [here](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~jensen/Algebra/ThmsGroups.pdf) shows that $x$ has at most $2$ fixed points.  We also know that $x$ must have order $2$ or $19$.  These two facts together show that either $x$ is a $19$-cycle or $x$ is the product of $9$ disjoint transpositions.  We are done in the latter case because $x$ is an odd permutation, a contradiction.

If $x$ is a $19$-cycle, then theorem $(P)$ of the above reference shows that $|N_{A_{20}}(P)|=171$.  But we know that $|N_G(P)|=38$, contradicting Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: If x is not in the centralizer, then x has order 2 (P is abelian). We need to know that such an x exists (that N≠C); this is Burnside's transfer theorem.

Comment: If N=C, then G also has a normal subgroup of size 2, which can avoid BTT (which gives a normal subgroup of index 19).