# How to show that group of order 760 is not simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, simple-groups

> How to show that group of order 760 is not simple?

By Sylow's theorem $n_{19}=20$, and $o(N(P)) = 38$, but how to continue after this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: How many 5-Sylow subgroups can there be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question on Simple Groups](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370604/question-on-simple-groups)

Comment: Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370731/groups-with-20-sylow-subgroups for a follow up

Answer (score 3):

I really cannot understand why people are voting to close this question! In the permutation action of the group by conjugation on its set of $20$ Sylow $19$-subgroups, an element of order $2$ normalizing a $19$-cycle would consist of $9$ transpositions, and hence would be an odd permutation. So intersecting with the alternating group gives a normal subgroup of index $2$.

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate. It seems completely on topic to me, and showed more work than the original one.